# Poker odds calculation of winning hand type

Tags: math, probability

There are a lot of libraries that calculate the winning probability of texas holdem poker player and the probability of each player having some combinations(pair, straight...). Does anyone know where I can find a library which calculates the probability of winning combination only. For example I want to know how much is the probability of straight or full house winning the table no matter which player wins.